# how to use angularjs controller in angular 5 - hybrid application (angularjs and angular)

Tags: angularjs, angular

we have our application written in angularjs, we are not migrating slowly to use angular, as we already have lot of other controller and directives in angularjs, i am planning to create the hybrid application.

I am trying to use the angularjs controller in a angular component, how can i make this work,

```
    <!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<div style="text-align:center" style="height: 800px;width: 800px;">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
  <button (click)="addItem()">add item</button>
  <gridster [options]="options">
      <gridster-item [item]="item" *ngFor="let item of dashboard">
          <div (mousedown)="$event.stopPropagation()" (touchstart)="$event.stopPropagation()">
              Some content to click without dragging the widget
            </div>
            <div class="item-buttons">
              <button md-icon-button md-raised-button class="drag-handler">                  
                  <div style="width: 50px;height: 50px">open_with</div>
              </button>
              <button md-icon-button md-raised-button class="remove-button" (click)="removeItem($event, item)"
                      (touchstart)="removeItem($event, item)" mdTooltip="Remove">
                <div style="width: 50px;height: 50px">clear</div>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
                First Name:
                <input type="text" ng-model="firstName">
                <br> Last Name:
                <input type="text" ng-model="lastName">
                <br>
                <br> Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}
              </div>
      </gridster-item>
    </gridster>
</div>
```

In the above code, i have added following portion, which uses angularjs controller. But my application is not working, if i use side by side, it works.

```
 <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
                First Name:
                <input type="text" ng-model="firstName">
                <br> Last Name:
                <input type="text" ng-model="lastName">
                <br>
                <br> Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}
              </div>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to have an application that uses AngularJS middleware and Angular middleware? Do you think this is a good idea? I don't know what exactly the error you have, but maybe it's a good information for you this: https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone ngzone is an Angular service for execute code inside or outside of Angular zone

Comment: yes, because we have a pretty large application built with angularjs and now slowly we are adding few angular components,

Comment: But now you have an application with 2 different frameworks working independently (and not a "light-weight" frameworks) if it's a big app, maybe you will have a performance penalty. By the way, about your question, what is exactly the error you have? Or there is not an error and simply the controller is not doing its job, have you check if it instances?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21225 i am getting the error something similar to this,

Comment: https://ufile.io/6yp8g i have copied my sample application here

Comment: It would be better if you copy your app in a jsfiddle or something like that to have a directly executed version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169459/discussion-between-kalamarico-and-shyam).